# Detect when the user completes his/her typing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little issue detecting when the user completes his/her typing down on a text box. The simplest case I have right now is to see if s/he hits the enter key. Because at present, my monitor screen reports the user entered keys are recorded as

```
T
To
Tod
Toda
Today [the user presses Enter]
```

Instead, I would want to get only `Today`. Is there any way to achieve this recording not using a timer to observe user's keyboard activities ?

Comment: What event are you presently using and what is your code for it? Add these to your question text and you might solve your problem quicker.

Comment: Is this Forms, WPF or ASP?

Comment: Side note: you need to precisely define "completes typing" for the question to be answerable. Right now it is more of "please help me understand what I want" kind of question rather than ask for solving particular programming issues.

Comment: Agree with @AnthonyPegram.  What is the use-case that requires you to detect the completion.  Not that it cannot be done, but should it be?  For example, I get interrupted alot at work, if my attention goes to that person while I am entering in your field then I am not done, but the code says I was.  I have used the enter key, the field losing focus, and enter/submit buttons for things like that in the past.  It really depends on what you are doing.

Comment: So, what's wrong with recording entered text after user presses Enter? Before that you can't know whether user typing word `To`, or `Today`, or `Tomorrow`

Comment: Thanks, I don't have chances or time to work on only one project. My life and my life necessities `in my area` ask me to concentrate and work more on different `things` at the same time. If you do have good chances to work on only C#, ASP.NET or Ruby On Rails etc to be a professional workman in your area, then you are really blessed. Experience taught me to respect what I do have now and learn to expect better things in the future. 
Thank you a lot for your comments and replies.

Answer (score 1):

Using a timer to monitor inactivity is the best tool you have. They only one who knows that what you call 'a user has finished' typing, is you. And in this particular case you state that the user must be finished when the word 'Today' is on the screen. But, perhaps your user want's to search for 'Todays' or 'Tod'? Or 'Todayabolenski'? (you know ;) that famous Russian writer from 'Fictionavsky Literatzky')

One other option would be is to have a word book file, which against you match the input. But still, some confusing things might happen when a users really is looking for that smaller word   which only appears as the beginning of a larger word in your word book.

Answer (score 1):

Your user won't press the Enter key, he presses the Tab key.  Which is the standard key to move the focus to another control in a GUI app.  Or he clicks a button, like the OK button of a dialog.  Also the button that's automatically activated when he pressed the Enter key.

Now you know he's done typing.  The Validating event for the TextBox will fire.  You can use that to do anything you want, including actually validating and complaining if the input is not acceptable.